# How to write an excludes if exists query

Tags: sql

I need to write a query to showcase users who visited my website, unless they visited in 2008.

So if they visited in the year 2008, I do not want them part of the chart, even if they visited in different years.

How can I write a query that excludes all user activity and data in my table if they visited in 2008?

I have

Unique Username
User ID
Date

Comment: which is the  database ?

Comment: So Ive joined where my table is not have the following Colums:
Unique Username Mike Smith
User ID 12345
Date 2008-01-01

If data goes from 2005 - 2015, I want to show all information, except all information that includes Mike Smith because he visisted in 2008. Because he visted that one time, I want exclude his visits  in all other years as well

Answer (score 1):

One method is `not exists`:

```
select . . .
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.userid = t.userid and
                        t2.date >= '2008-01-01' and
                        t2.date < '2009-01-01'
                 );
```

Comment: So would this query exclude users who visited in 2008, and any other data the userid  is assigned to, and showcase everything else is the table?

Comment: @AndrewSarrazin . . . This removes all users who have a record at any time during 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is `EXCEPT`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT "User"
FROM "t"
EXCEPT
SELECT "User"
FROM "t"
WHERE "Date" BETWEEN '2008-01-01' and '2009-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

One more method is using analytics function:

```
select ...
from 
(
select t.*, sum(case when date between '2008-01-01' and '2008-12-31' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by userid) as cnt_2008
  from t
) s
where s.cnt_2008 = 0
```